# Can we use LinearConstraint to replace Bounds in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

I am working on a minimize problem that has some bounds and linear constraints. If I want to define bounds on a function's variables, `0< x_1, x_2`, can I write this bounds in a LinearConstraints format? For example:

```py
lb = [0, 0, 0]
ub = [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]

linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([[0,0,-1,1], [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], lb=lb, ub=ub)
```

Does the above make any difference from the following:

```
bnds=[(0, np.inf)] * 2

lb = [0]
ub = [np.inf]
linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([[0,0,-1,1], lb=lb, ub=ub)
```

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your actual minimize call and the setup required for it to run

Comment: @Reinderien Why? Is it case by case? The first block of code is putting the linear constraints and bounds in a matrix format, and the second is separating them.